# Displaying only the file name Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Kinda new to PHP, trying to display only the file name for uploaded pdf's in my custom info box, not the complete url or ID. Been at it for two days searching the net and trying the code examples on acf homepage.

this is my current code:

```
        <div class="post-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <!-- advanced custom fields plugin content -->
            <?php 
            if( function_exists('get_field')) {
                if (get_field('product_info_content') OR get_field('product_info_file')  OR get_field('product_info_file_2') ) {
                    echo '<div class="info-box">';
                    echo '<h1>' . get_field('product_info_title') . '</h1>';
                    the_field('product_info_content');
                    echo '<ul>';
                        echo '<li class="product_info_list_item">';
                        the_field('product_info_file_1');
                        echo '</li>';
                        echo '<li class="product_info_list_item">';
                        the_field('product_info_file_2');
                        echo '</li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</div>';

                }
            }
            ?><!-- end advanced custom field -->
```

what I'm trying to active with little to no luck is echoing out the name of the file of product_info_file_1 and 2 as an link that opens in a new window.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your field name is not uniform in `if` check and in display. You can try following code. This will display the link of file uploaded.

```
<?php
if( function_exists('get_field')) {
  if (get_field('product_info_content') OR get_field('product_info_file_1')
    OR get_field('product_info_file_2') ) {
    echo '<div class="info-box">';
    echo '<h1>' . get_field('product_info_title') . '</h1>';
    the_field('product_info_content');
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li class="product_info_list_item">';
    $file_1 = get_field('product_info_file_1');
    if ( ! empty( $file_1 ) ) {
      echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $file_1['url'] ) . '" target="_blank">' . esc_html( $file_1['title'] ) . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
    echo '<li class="product_info_list_item">';
    $file_2 = get_field('product_info_file_2');
    if ( ! empty( $file_2 ) ) {
      echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $file_2['url'] ) . '" target="_blank">' . esc_html( $file_2['title'] ) . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';

  }
}
?><!-- end advanced custom field -->
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you! (had some issues at first, before i realized that one of the fields had a return value set to url.)

Comment: Im a bit curious o this:

Comment: . esc_html( $file_1['title'] ) .

this outputs the title of the file right?, is ['title'] a predefined php function?

 if i wanted to lets say append the file typ efter the title or insert an icon infront of the title.

Comment: `$file_1` contains the information of file. You can dump that variable check the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but I used preg_match() to get the last word in the path so that way I can get the file name.

`<?PHP`

`preg_match("/[^\/]+$/",get_field('filename'), $matches);`

`echo str_replace('-',' ',$matches[0]);`

`?>`